# Check input to create a valid triangle

Tags: c#, math

I'm doing a task where the user enters three sides of a triangle to calculate the base area and the circumference. I have to uppdate my code because it was not accepted by the teacher. I must do some kind of check to make sure the values make a valid triangle. I search and found some info about Triangle Inequality Theorem and it's about The sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the length of the third side

So if I'm getting this right, I have the values A, B and C and I'm going to sum A + B to check if this is greater than C and sum A + C it this is greater than B and finally check if the sum of B + C is greater than A before a calculation is done. Is this correct? Help is preciated!

Comment: Probably better on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You're off topic here.  But you have the general idea right, Google for the *triangle inequality*.

Comment: not true however, you can have two lengths of 10 and one length of 15 and it is a valid triangle even though 10 + 10 is 20 which is greater than 15...

Comment: Hmm the good old triangle might fail your case for sides `2,3,5`

Comment: @RhysW yeah thats what it means sum of two sides (20) greater than third (15)

Comment: my mistake i read this backwards...

Comment: this should help http://www.freemathhelp.com/feliz-triangle-inequalities.html

Comment: It is sufficient that the sum of the two shorter sides is larger than the longest side. Of course, checking the three sums is not more work than sorting and checking one sum, when done programmatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your approach summing up the lengths of two sides and comparing them to the third side is correct, but you must do so for *every* pair of lines.

```
a + b > c
a + c > b
b + c > a
```

Only if all three of these are true, you have a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all. *Every* set of three points you choose forms a valid triange, *unless* they are all on the same straight line.

Comment: technically only true on 2 planes, viewing it from a side on view would appear that the triangle is one long line where in reality its extending into the third plane, therefore its a valid triangle unless all three points are the exact same point

Comment: Hmm not where did points come in he is talking about sides

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he doesn't enter points, but the lengths of the three sides. And this may allow incorrect inputs.

Comment: but these sides would have to have ends to them, which would be the points he is talkign about

Comment: So what's the endpoint for a triangle side with length 5?

Comment: 5 greater than the start point of said line...

Comment: regardless of where in space the triangle is the points would still have the same relative distance between them, thus an equilateral triangle of length 5 at point 00 is the same as an equilateral triangle of length 5 at point 20,20, the exact co-ordinates dont matter, its the fact the 3 points in space would create a triangle

Comment: You don't understand: He's not talking about points! The input to the program is `4, 3, 2`, each of the values being the *length* of one side. There are not points. While of course a line must have a start and end point, the program has no knowledge of them.

Comment: i see the point you are making, if youll excuse the pun, i see exactly what youre saying and i agree, the problem here is youre not seeing our point under the same light we are, both our statements are one in the same, youre just thinking of it as lengths between points were thinking of it as points between lengths, just some minor confusion is all.

Comment: Well, in that case zmbq's answer is not an answer to the question at all. You're making too many assumptions, for example that any couple of "sides" of the shape he's trying to check share one point. This is not given.

Comment: no i see now where i am mistaken, i re-read the question and see it is about entering sides and seeing if that is valid, not looking at an existing triangle and seeing if it is valid, sorry for my mix up and thankyou for pushing til i saw my own mistakes

Comment: No problem. Sorry for mistaking the answer as your answer - I fixed my comment to point out that zmbq's answer is not really an answer to the question.